# Laravel eloquent multiple WHERE

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new in php/laravel.

I'm trying to get one user with the userName of the user connected except if it's "Chuck NORRIS"

This, is working. I'm getting the user connected information

```
  $oneUser= User::where('name', $userName)->get();
```

This, is not working. I'm getting the user Chuck NORRIS if he's the one connected

```
 $oneUser= User::where('name', $userName)->where($userName, '!=', "Chuck NORRIS")->get();
```

Comment: you have to pass attribute name in first parameter, not a variable, just use `$oneUser = User::whereNot('name', "Chuck NORRIS")->where('name', $userName)->get();`

Comment: Thank you !! I've mix my way and yours and it's working perfectly :)

Comment: also if you are only trying to get one user use `first` not `get`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i've done and what is working :

```
$oneUser = User::where('name', '!=', "Chuck NORRIS")->where('name', $userName)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($userName != "Chuck NORRIS") {
  $oneUser= User::where('name', $userName)->get();
}
else{
return back();
}
```

this should work, you check is the $userName is Chuck NORRIS
if not, then run the query
otherwise return back

Answer (score 0):

```php
$userName = "input text";

$oneUser= User::query()->when($userName!="Chuck NORRIS",function($query) use($userName) {
 $query->where('name', $userName);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use "whereNot" query like this:

```
 $oneUser= User::where('name', $userName)->whereNot($userName,"Chuck NORRIS")->first();
```